# How to upload video on twitter using twitvid in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to upload video on twitter using twitvid api. I have found this "http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/file/44841746/TwitVidSDK-iOS.zip" but again facing error "'upload' REQUEST '87c60K0W' DID FAIL WITH ERROR: Error Domain=TVErrorBackendDomain Code=1001 "Could not authenticate with OAuth." UserInfo=0x6d33670 {NSLocalizedDescription=Could not authenticate with OAuth.}". Sorry for my english. I am unable to track the error... Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a developer account in twitter and then create your application their.You will got secret key and app key.use this key to Authenticate  your app and then through twitter api you can upload video .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a new Twitter Application then you will see Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Token Key ... in details of this application. After that, replace them in TwitVidSampleViewController.m and start running again.